# php session variables not working on index.php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have some `$_SESSION` variables that are working correctly on my entire website:

`print_r($_SESSION)` prints

`Array ( [first_name] => Daniel [last_name] => Jameson [email] => email@gmail.com [logged_in] => 1 )`

However, for some reason on index.php the variables are all unset:

`print_r($_SESSION)` prints

`Array ( )`

If I rename index.php to index2.php they all work! This implies that the code itself it fine, but for some reason the filename/path for index.php is the problem.

I recently was whitelisted for a mod_security block, could that be the cause of the problem? Maybe something to do with file permissions? It's beyond my expertise...

**EDIT**

If I try a URL like `.../index.php?blah` it works as expected. Thinking that it was a caching issue I added:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, private, no-cache, must-revalidate');     // HTTP/1.1
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, max-stale = 0', false);  // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');                  // Date in the past  
header('Expires: 0', false); 
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
```

But index.php still unsets the `$_SESSION` variables. Even though I have also cleared the cache.

Comment: ok, test again but add random keyword after index.php like this: index.php?anytext  to check if index.php cached or not

Comment: Yes, it is being cached! How would I prevent this happening? And why is it only happening on index.php and not other pages?

Comment: Please [edit] this question with the new information from the duplicate question you've asked. The duplicate will be removed soon.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that your function session_start() is setted before everything in your code.
A reason why $_SESSION Can't be set : 
When you set a $_SESSION just before a header. So you should put the function session_write_close() just before the header.
Or a problem with your cache.